# do-while loop with timeout

Tags: powershell

I have the following loop:

```
$output = (command)
do {
something
} while ($output -match "some string")
```

Which works fine. I want to add a timeout to the loop, how do I do that? The expectation is that at some point the output won't match the string but I don't want it to run forever if the output matches the string forever.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your question

Comment: no problem, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 18):

Just use the `Get-Date` cmdlet and check for that in your `while` condition. Example:

```
$startDate = Get-Date

$output = (command)
do {
something
} while ($output -match "some string" -and $startDate.AddMinutes(2) -gt (Get-Date))
```

Comment: thats pretty neat!

Comment: Definitely the way to go. Notice that `$output` stays the same in the original example, due to nothing ever being assigned to it inside the `do{}while()` loop

Comment: one quick question here. When you assign the output of a command to a variable like this, does powershell run the command everytime it checks the value of the variable?

Comment: No, the variable gets assigned with the result of the command you invoked. PowerShell wont invoke it again.

Comment: I see, then I should include $output=(command) line within the loop, right?

Comment: yes, as Mathias mentioned. Otherwise you will get an endless loop. You could also write `(command) -match "some string"` in your while conditon instead. So you don't have to assign the output in your do loop.

Answer (score 6):

Although using the `Get-Date` Cmdlet is valid, a cleaner approach would be to use the [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8) class, which is available in .NET Core >= 1.0.

```
$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds 5
$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
do {
    # do stuff here
} while ($stopwatch.elapsed -lt $timeout)
```

Sources:

1. https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2012/01/14/making-a-timed-loop-in-powershell/
2. https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/10/19/using-a-stopwatch-in-powershell.aspx
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-timespan?view=powershell-6